# Split an array in three part according to a provided index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to split an array of n elements in 3 parts according to a provided index (in the picture below the index is 3):

[image]

I tried this, but in some cases it does not work.

```js
const split = (array, index) => {
  const requestedItem = array[index];
  const rightItems = array.slice(index + 1);
  const leftItems = array.slice(0, index);

  return {
    requestedItem,
    leftItems,
    rightItems
  };
}

console.log(split(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], 1));
console.log(split(['item1'], 0));
```

Comment: Have a look slice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: why on example2 the rightItems is empty? is that right? shouldn't it be ['item2', 'item3', 'item4'] ?

Comment: Yes, I already did with slice. However, in the case I only have one element I don't have a proper behave.

Comment: oh i forgot the array is only one item

Comment: Could you post what you did to try solve this?

Comment: Updated with my trial

Comment: Your script works as intended(*). The only problem is you that you don't understand how `.slice()` works. Either re-read the documentation or just swap "left" and "right".

Comment: My bad, I wrote too fast the method but I do understand what slice do ^^

Comment: And now after the last edit it works as requested. So what's the problem?

Comment: My bad the problem was not from that... I would have double check.

Comment: What is your desired output? array or object?

Comment: _"My bad the problem was not from that"_ - So the question is useless because it works? Then why accept an answer that does exactly the same as your script?

Comment: To please someone who took the time to answer..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no problem at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```js
const splitArray = (arr, index) => {
    return [
        arr.slice(0, index), 
        [arr[index]], 
        arr.slice(index + 1)
    ];
}

const array1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
const array2 = ['item1'];

console.log(splitArray(array1, 1));
console.log(splitArray(array2, 0));
console.log(splitArray(array1, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just split with the given index.

```js
function split(array, index) {
     return [
         array.slice(0, index),
         array.slice(index, index + 1),
         array.slice(index + 1)
     ];
}

console.log(split(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], 1));
/*
leftItems = ['item1'];
requestedItem = ['item2'];
rightItems = ['item3', 'item4'];
*/

console.log(split(['item1'], 0));
/*
leftItems = [];
requestedItem = ['item1'];
rightItems = [];
*/

console.log(split(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], 3));
/*
leftItems = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
requestedItem = ['item4'];
rightItems = [];
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 slices

```js
function splitOnIndex(array, index) {
  const leftItems = array.slice(0, index);
  const requestedItem = array.slice(index, index + 1);
  const rightItems = array.slice(index + 1);

  return [leftItems, requestedItem, rightItems];
}

var [left, requested, right] = splitOnIndex(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], 1);
console.log(left, requested, right);

[left, requested, right] = splitOnIndex(['item1'], 0);
console.log(left, requested, right);

[left, requested, right] = splitOnIndex(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], 3);
console.log(left, requested, right);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
const index = 2;

leftItems = array.slice(0, index);
requestedItem = array[index];
rightItems = array.slice(index+1, array.length);
```